# Extracting a list from a class in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is the thing, I would like to extract a chart from a website and put it into a list. Here is what I have tried
Let's say there is an HTML class like this:

```
<div AAA class="body">
   <div BBB class="id">
       <span CCC> 123456 </span> </div>
   <div BBB class="Date">
       <div DDD> "Feb 02" <br> </div>
   <div BBB class="Class">
       <div DDD> "English" <br> "101" </div>
</div>
```

Here is what I have tried with C#

```
List<IWebElement> card_list = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("body")).ToList();
            foreach (IWebElement bet in card_list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",bet.Text);
            }
```

Of course that will return the whole thing. What I want is to separate every part of the body into parts, like "Id: 123456, Date: Feb 02, Class: English 101".
Please tell me what I should try for it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below xpath to get list of elements.

```
List<IWebElement> card_list = driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("//div[@class = 'body']/div[@BBB]")).ToList();
            foreach (IWebElement bet in card_list)
            {
                String prop = bet.get_attribute("class");
                String val = bet.Text;
                Console.WriteLine(prop + " : " + val);
            }
```

Comment: Nope, it returns nothing.